# Spacing after Mr./Mrs./Ms.?

Tags: punctuation

Should I put a space after Mr./Mrs./Ms.?

In other words, should it be "Mr.Jones" or "Mr. Jones?"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.

"Mrs." and "Jones" are separate words so a space must be placed between them.

It may be worth noting that in Commonwealth English, no full-stop is included for abbreviations that consist of the first and last letters of a word, e.g. the American English "Dr. Jones" would be rendered "Dr Jones".

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course you should give a space after these words. These are just like any other word and we should treat them like regular words.
We always put spaces between two words.

Ex. Mr. Peter (correct)

Ex. Mr.Peter (incorrect)